# Dragging on html table cells

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, web

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/LtRN8/4/)

```
$(document).live('mouseup', function () {
    flag = false;
});

var colIndex;
var lastRow;

$(document).on('mousedown', '.csstablelisttd', function (e) {
    //This line gets the index of the first clicked row.
    lastRow = $(this).closest("tr")[0].rowIndex;

    var rowIndex = $(this).closest("tr").index();
    colIndex = $(e.target).closest('td').index();
    $(".csstdhighlight").removeClass("csstdhighlight");
    if (colIndex == 0 || colIndex == 1) //)0 FOR FULL TIME CELL AND 1 FOR TIME SLOT CELL. 
    return;
    if ($('#contentPlaceHolderMain_tableAppointment tr').eq(rowIndex).find('td').eq(colIndex).hasClass('csstdred') == false) {
        $('#contentPlaceHolderMain_tableAppointment tr').eq(rowIndex).find('td').eq(colIndex).addClass('csstdhighlight');

        flag = true;
        return false;
    }
});
```

i am Dragging on table cells.
While dragging(move downward direction) i have to move table scroll also.
and also i want to select cells reverse (upward direction).
what should i do.

I have make an selection on tr class.

Comment: Please refer this you will get some idea for dragging the table cells using jquery [JQury plugin for table drag and drop](http://isocra.com/2008/02/table-drag-and-drop-jquery-plugin/) [drag and drop table row from on table to another](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14907809/drag-and-drop-table-row-from-one-tabs-) thanks in advance

Comment: From what understand, you want to **select rows** by dragging the mouse over them, instead of dragging the rows up or down. Is that right ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Select Cells On A Table By Dragging](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2013902/select-cells-on-a-table-by-dragging)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Updated jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/qvxBb/2/

Disable normal selection like this:

```
.myselect {
    -webkit-touch-callout: none;
    -webkit-user-select: none;
    -khtml-user-select: none;
    -moz-user-select: moz-none;
    -ms-user-select: none;
    user-select: none;
}
```

And handle the row-selection with javascript like this:

```
// wether or not we are selecting
var selecting = false;
// the element we want to make selectable
var selectable = '.myselect tr:not(:nth-child(1)) td:nth-child(3)';

$(selectable).mousedown(function () {
    selecting = true;
}).mouseenter(function () {
    if (selecting) {
        $(this).addClass('csstdhighlight');
        fillGaps();
    }
});
$(window).mouseup(function () {
    selecting = false;
}).click(function () {
    $(selectable).removeClass('csstdhighlight');
});

// If you select too fast, js doesn't fire mousenter on all cells. 
// So we fill the missing ones by hand
function fillGaps() {
    min = $('td.csstdhighlight:first').parent().index();
    max = $('td.csstdhighlight:last').parent().index();
    $('.myselect tr:lt('+max+'):gt('+min+') td:nth-child(3)').addClass('csstdhighlight');
}
```

I just added a class in the HTML. All the HTML and CSS in unchanged besides what I've shown here.

Updated jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/qvxBb/2/

Comment: @Means Just ask you question... This is not instant messaging.

Comment: if I properly understand the [`user select` compatibility table](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/user-select#Browser_compatibility), only the `-moz-` prefix is still required.

Answer (score 3):

There are several problems with your table, but I will correct the one you asked for.
To make your table scroll when your mouse get outside the container, add this code inside your `mousedown` event handler :

```
$('body').on('mousemove', function(e){
    div = $('#divScroll');      
    if(e.pageY > div.height() && (e.pageY - div.height()) > div.scrollTop()) {
        div.scrollTop(e.pageY - div.height());
    }
});
```

and this, inside your `mouseup` event handler :

```
$('body').off('mousemove');
```

See the **[updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/LtRN8/7/)**

But now, another issue appear. This is because of the rest of your code. The lines are not selected because the mouse leave the column.

Comment: Thanks for your reply....  cell selection be upward and downward direction on Student name coloumn..How should i do

Answer (score 3):

Try removing the `return false;` inside

```
$('#contentPlaceHolderMain_tableAppointment tr').eq(rowIndex).find('td').eq(colIndex).addClass('csstdhighlight');
    flag = true;
    return false; //Remove this line
}
```

Because `return false;` stops browser default behavior (scrolling automatically).

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/LtRN8/8/)

Comment: Khanh i have to go upward and downward direction on Student name coloumn...not first and second column...\