# Multi-select rows in bootstrap table

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3, bootstrap-table

I want to multi-select the rows in bootstrap table and  re-order them  using drag and drop option. Any suggestions or links to achieve this would be helpful..

Comment: Check if this is of any help [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14907809/drag-and-drop-table-row-from-one-tabs-table-to-another-tabs-table-jquery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14907809/drag-and-drop-table-row-from-one-tabs-table-to-another-tabs-table-jquery)

Comment: Use Jquery Sortable
http://johnny.github.io/jquery-sortable/

Comment: @nolawipetros It doesn't have an example for multi-select rows..

Answer (score -1):

Use [datatables](https://datatables.net/examples/api/select_row.html)

example js see below

```
$(document).ready(function() {
var table = $('#example').DataTable();

$('#example tbody').on( 'click', 'tr', function () {
    $(this).toggleClass('selected');
} );

$('#button').click( function () {
    alert( table.rows('.selected').data().length +' row(s) selected' );
} );
} );
```

Comment: This example helps to multi-select the rows. Any pointers on implementing drag and drop functionality for the same?